# Run Eclipse using the search (super button)

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, eclipse

quasi-newbie to Ubuntu here.

I have Eclipse running properly and everything. The issue is that when I hit the Super key, if I type eclipse into the search, it doesn't find it/ allow me to run eclipse.

For Firefox or Terminal, I just start typing them and they show up. Is there a way I can set this up for Eclipse as well?

Comment: a few questions: 1) what is the output of which eclipse? 2) is there currently a .deskto file of eclipse in either `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications` 3) if so, could you post it in either a comment or your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create .desktop file for your program (eclipse.desktop in your case). Then put it to /usr/share/applications directory or ~/.local/share/applications if you want it to be accessible for one user only. It is easier to create the file on the desktop first and test it before copying to its destined directory.

Basic stucture of a .desktop file is something like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Sample Application Name
Comment=A sample application
Exec=application
Icon=application.png
Terminal=false
```

In Exec field you put a command you want to run (eclipse). I think all other fields are self descriptive. If you want more detailed information about .desktop file then there is a lot of info online.

Comment: I tried something like this earlier, and it didn't seem to work. In Exec, I put the path to the file (`/Documents/eclipse/eclipse`) and I tried putting `eclipse` plain, but neither seemed to work. Does it need to refresh or something?

Comment: /Documents/eclipse/eclipse is probably not your absolute path to the program. In exec you should put only "eclipse" (if your eclipse executable is in your PATH) or an absolute path to the executable. (Oh my.. pressed Enter and my comment got submitted, lol) Absolute path could be something like /home/<your username here>/Documents/eclipse/eclipse or ~/Documents/eclipse/eclipse (be careful with this one since it won't work for other user).

Comment: Hmm interesting. So I tried using the absolute path, that still didn't seem to work. How do I add eclipse to PATH?

Comment: `~` is not working in a `.desktop` file.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I didn't have `~` in the file. However, I'm not really sure what I did differently but it just started working. Thanks All